# how to kill proccess created by socket in python?

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I have a problem with terminating a process created by socket in python.

So I wanted to create a UDP server in python, so I did socket.bind() to bind IP address and port to the server, I got some error in program and then again...I tried to use socket.bind() again, but it says it is already in use.

After a while I found out in Resource Monitor that I have this "connection" there.

[image: socket in Resource Monitor]

My .py file:

```py
serverIP = input()
serverPort = int(input())

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

try:
   server_socket.bind((serverIP, serverPort))
except OSError:
   print("Already in use")
   return
```

I cannot terminate in control panel that process because it says: *Access denied*.
I cannot terminate it through cmd with admin rights.
Reboot does not help.

Any ideas how to close it?

Comment: "Reboot does not help". If it really is a process, surely it does. No process survives a reboot.

Comment: (But no, you can't kill the System process.)

Comment: Use a different port. Typically want a port >1024 if you aren’t admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to identify the PID of the process (with the task manager or the `tasklist` command

Then kill the task using powershell with `taskkill /PID <PID_HERE>`

**EDIT :** Apparently port 137 is used by NetBIOS Name Service, so check with the Windows firewall

Comment: it says access denied

Comment: Have you tried with admin privileges ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried